# Applying Bayes Theorem to find the probability of a finite intersection of events

Tags: probability, notation, bayes-theorem

I have a notation problem. Let $A$ and $B$ be events such that $P(B)\ne 0$. The by Bayes' theorem, $$ P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)~~~~~~~~~(1) $$

Similarly, $$ P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(A|B \cap C)P(B\cap C) = P(A|B\cap C)P(B|C)P(C)~.$$

My question is the following:

How would I represent the following: $$ P\left(\cap_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right)$$ using (1).

**Added**

For $n =4$, I get

$$P\left(\cap_{i=1}^4 A_i\right) = P\left(A_1 |\cap_{i=2}^4 A_i\right)\cdot P\left(A_2 |\cap_{i=3}^4 A_i\right)\cdot P\left(A_3 |\cap_{i=4}^4 A_i\right) \cdot P(A_4)$$

Comment: Have you tried writing in it when there are $4$ events?  I think you'll notice a pattern.

Comment: Also, a small technical point, this technically isn't Bayes' Theorem; this is the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: @MarcusM I  have added to my question. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Try to generalize from there.

Comment: @MarcusM Will it be $$P\left(\cap_{i=1}^{n}  A_i\right) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}P\left(A_i |\cap_{j=i+1}^n A_j\right)\cdot P(A_n)$$

Comment: Using `\mid` instead of `|` results in proper spacing.

Comment: Note: you can "pull off" the $A_i$'s in any order, depending on what makes the probabilities easiest to calculate. So you could also write
$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = \prod_{i=2}^n P\left(A_i \Bigg\vert \bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j\right) \cdot P(A_1)$$
and there are other possibilities as well.

Comment: @joriki noted. thanks

Comment: @kccu Thanks for your comment.